# Eclipse content assist shows some javadocs but not others

Tags: java, eclipse

For example, when I type

```
Scanner s;
s.
```

then, right after I type the '.' one popup windows comes up with all the Scanner methods, the first one being highlighted, and a second popup window comes up with the javadoc for that first method (close()). I can use the up and down arrows to select different methods and their docs show up in the second popup. Awesome.

But, when I type:

```
String s;
s.
```

then I get the first popup with the methods but not the second popup with the method's javadoc. How do I get that second popup to pop up?

I *think* this was working before...not sure.

I'm on a Mac.

I visited Preferences->installed JREs and took a look at the current value, which is JVM 1.6.0 (Mac Os X Default). All the Javadoc Locations there point to http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api. Maybe there was some problem downloading these docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh, after posting I noticed the url now forwards to oracle so I changed the javadoc URLS to http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/ and now it works.